# Human verification on failing to include necessary tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, captcha

On submitting a question here at Meta Stack Overflow, it is required to include a tag if it's a bug, feature-request or a discussion.  Failing to do so results in an error and returns you to the form.  After filling in the correct tag and submitting it again, the human verification form was shown.

IMO, when the error is the failure to include one of those tags and the form is re-submitted, the human verification should not be necessary because new meta stackoverflow users are bound to commit that error.

Better yet, use an input type that explicitly shows that those tags are required instead of letting them type it.  It could be a radio button or a drop down (not autocomplete) if only one of those tags should be included or a checkbox if 2 or more of those tags can be included.

Comment: No other answers?

Answer (score 2):

This could lead to very easy exploits where you send in a form missing a tag, then edit the form and resubmit it in order to never get a captcha (much easier to spam).

The radio buttons or drop down could be a decent addition, but it's honestly not that difficult to type in a tag.

Comment: They could reduce the chance of hitting the Captcha though.